# Vlookup not finding matching Date

Tags: date, vlookup

I'm trying to use VLOOKUP to get date values in one tab to match in another.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IeUT.png) is the tab in which I'm trying to use VLOOKUP.

[These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUUgp.png) are the two tabs in question.

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywp2y.png) is the other tab where lookup is supposed to happen.

Here is the formula I tried:

=VLOOKUP(LEFT(E2, 10), 'Week Numbering'!A:D, 4, FALSE)

As we can see from the first screenshot, I get a message that VLOOKUP can't find the search value in the location given. But as we can see in the 3rd screenshot, that same date is there in the other sheet.

I tried swapping the dates with a string of text in both tabs and then the lookup worked, so the issue must have something to do with date formats. However, I confirmed that in both tabs, ISDATE and ISNUMBER return 'True' while ISTEXT returns 'False'.

Any ideas why VLOOKUP can't find the date? Thank you.

Comment: the 'Left' function changes the type to a string, which is different than the numeric type that is a date.  Does your formula work w/o the 'Left" part and just using E2?

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you!